# How can I make a .bat file into a GUI .exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to create an application to shutdown my PC depending on the time I set before I start watching a movie.

I made it in a .bat file which is here:

```
@echo off
:BEGINING
echo  ________________________
echo / 30 min                 /
echo / 45 min                 /
echo / 1 hour                 /
echo / 1 hour 30 mins (1.30)  /
echo / 1 hour 45 min (1.45)   /
echo / 2 hours                /
echo / 2 hours 30 min (2.30)  /
echo / 2 hours 45 min (2.45)  /
echo  ------------------------
set /p hourShutdown=Shutdown in: 
if %hourShutdown%==0.30 (
    ::Shutting down in 30 minutes
    set /p youSure=Shutting down in 30 minutes? Y/N: 
    goto CONFIRMATION30
)
if %hourShutdown%==0.45 (
    set /p youSure=Shutting down in 45 minutes? Y/N: 
    goto CONFIRMATION45
)
if %hourShutdown%==1 (
    ::Shutting down in 1 hour
    set /p youSure=Shutting down in %hourShutdown% hour? S/N: 
    goto CONFIRMATION1
)
if %hourShutdown%==1.30 (
    ::Shutting down in 1 hour and media
    set /p youSure=Shutting down in 1 hour 30 minutes? Y/N: 
    goto CONFIRMATION130
)
if %hourShutdown%==1.45 (
    ::Shutting down in 1 hour and 45 minutes
    set /p youSure=Shutting down in 1 hour and 45 minutes? Y/N: 
    goto CONFIRMATION145
)
if %hourShutdown%==2 (
    ::Shutting down in 2 hours
    set /p youSure=Shutting down in %hourShutdown% hours? Y/N: 
    goto CONFIRMATION2
)
if %hourShutdown%==2.30 (
    ::Shutting down in 2 hours 30 minutes
    set /p youSure=Shutting down in 2 hours and 30 minutes? Y/N: 
    goto CONFIRMATION230
)
if %hourShutdown%==2.45 (
    ::Shutting down in 2 hours 45 minutes
    set /p youSure=Shutting down in 2 hours and 45 minutes? Y/N: 
    goto CONFIRMATION245
) else (
    echo Time incorrectly introduced...
    goto BEGINING
)
:CONFIRMATION30
if %youSure%==y (
    shutdown -s -t 1800
) else (
    goto BEGINING
)
:CONFIRMATION45
if %youSure%==y (
    shutdown -s -t 2700
    exit
) else (
    goto BEGINING
)
:CONFIRMATION1
if %youSure%==y (
    shutdown -s -t 3600
    exit
) else (
    goto BEGINING
)
:CONFIRMATION130
if %youSure%==y (
    shutdown -s -t 4680
    exit
) else (
    goto BEGINING
)
:CONFIRMATION145
if %youSure%==y (
    shutdown -s -t 5220
    exit
) else (
    goto BEGINING
)
:CONFIRMATION2
if %youSure%==y (
    shutdown -s -t 7200
    exit
) else (
    goto BEGINING
)
:CONFIRMATION230
if %youSure%==y (
    shutdown -s -t 8280
    exit
) else (
    goto BEGINING
)
:CONFIRMATION245
if %youSure%==y (
    shutdown -s -t 8820
    exit
) else (
    goto BEGINING
)
pause
```

Now that I made the .bat file I would like to make a GUI for it. I have made a research across Internet and I have found something called VBScript which I don´t need to install all Visual Basic Studio Software.

I barely have code skills, .bat code is the best I can code for now so **is there a way to make the .bat file into a GUI .exe with VBScript?**

Comment: Do not post links to code.  Put your code into your question.

Comment: You can do with [HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hta) (HTML Application) as GUI with vbscript

Comment: Here's a couple of links for the above; [1.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx) and [2.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692769.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No. Write it again in a programming language that allows you to create a GUI (and compiles to an executable, which VBScript does not).
Yes, you will have to learn a different programming language for this (at least small parts of it).

[Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) is free and a quick download away, it's also no longer as large and heavy as in older times.

Comment: @iBug: They mention Visual Studio in their question, particularly their unwillingness to install a huge, hulking behemoth. I pointed out that it isn't nearly that gargantuan anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can run things in Powershell. However that doesn't make it easier to migrate when it comes to the GUI part. You may wish to take a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx).